# ui-grid inside ui-grid in a cell template - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I would like to design a ui-grid inside another ui-grid (ui-grid inside a cellTemplate)

Can someone help me with this? I browsed in google, but am not able to find any solution.

Comment: Please explain what you have done so far.

Comment: 1. I have created a ui-grid and added a ui-grid as a cell template to that outer grid. 
2. I am able to surface the details as needed. 
3. For each of the row in the inner grid, am able to surface an edit button
4. But am not able to invoke the $scope method to perform actions corresponding to this Edit button in the inner grid. I tried ng-click="grid.appScope.EditMethod()", but this does not help.

Comment: Hi @KeerthanaValarmathi, welcome to SO. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39429735/edit) your question to share the code what you have written so far and explain what is your desired output and what is not working. You may also check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this by not having a grid, instead a div with ng-repeat to loop through the options and show the data